# looping through a rails data object from the controller

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, loops

I have called a function from a class to find all the items related to a particular ID in a many to many HABTM relationship.

Procedures -> Tasks      with a join table: procedures_tasks

I call the information like @example = Procedure.get_tasks(1,1)

I would like to be able to iterate through the data returned so that I can create an instance of each task_id related to the procedure in question

```
  def self.get_tasks(model_id, operating_system_id)
    find(:first,  :select => 'tasks.id, procedures.id', :conditions => ["model_id = ? AND operating_system_id = ?", model_id, operating_system_id], :include => [:tasks])
  end
```

I tried rendering the data as i normally would and then using .each do |f| in the view layer, but i get:

```
undefined method `each' for #<Procedure:0x2b879be1db30>
```

Original Question:

I am creating a rails application to track processes we perform. When a new instance of a process is created I want to automatically create rows for all the tasks that will need to be performed.
tables:

- decommissions
- models
- operating_systems
- procedures
- tasks
- procedures_tasks
- host_tasks

procedures -> tasks is many to many through the procedures_tasks join table.

when you start a new decommissioning process you specify a model and OS, the model and OS specify which procedure you follow, each procedure has a list of tasks available in the join table. I am wanting to create a entry in host_tasks for each task relevant to the procedure relevant to the decommission being created.

I've done my head in over this for days, any suggestions?

```
class Procedure < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tasks
 #has_many :tasks, :through => :procedures_tasks
# has_many :procedures_tasks
  belongs_to :model
  belongs_to :operating_system
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :operating_system_id
  validates_presence_of :model_id

  def self.get_tasks(model_id, operating_system_id)
    find(:first,  :select => 'tasks.id, procedures.id', :conditions => ["model_id = ? AND operating_system_id = ?", model_id, operating_system_id], :include => [:tasks])
  end

end
```

the get_tasks method will retrieve the tasks associated with the procedure, but I don't know how to manipulate the data pulled from the database in rails, I haven't been able to access the attributes of the returned object through the controller because they haven't been rendered yet?

ideally i would like to be able to format this data so that I only have an array of the task_id's which i can then loop through creating new rows in the appropriate table.

Comment: What do you mean by manipulate the data? Are you looking to have an HTML form that you can manage everything with?

Comment: There is a form for initiating the decommissioning process, you enter all the details which are added to the decommissions table. After this I would like to pull the decommission_id and all relevant task_id's and add them to the host_tasks table. I want to add those in on the controller level automatically.

When I say manipulate the data I mean strip it so that @example = [task_id1, task_id2, etc]

rather than having @example = "crazy ruby object with heaps of attributes nested within themselves"

Comment: I have found that i can access the sub attributes by going @tasks.task.name etc. is there a better way then to loop through all those and send an sql command for each? Is there a railsy way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't looping through because I was using the :first option when finding the data. I changed it to :all which allowed me to .each do |f| etc.

Not the best option, but there will only ever be one option anyway, so it won't cause a problem.